# Is it coherent to treat the C programming language as a formal system?

Tags: logic

*This is cross-posted from [a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4437649/is-it-coherent-to-treat-the-c-programming-language-as-a-formal-system) on Mathematics Stack Exchange, on the advice of a commenter.*

In mathematical logic, a **formal system** is a structure which includes, amongst other things, a set of axioms, and which is able to determine the truth or falsehood of statements with respect to those axioms.

A number of useful and counter-intuitive theorems were proved with respect to formal systems in the previous century. The Incompleteness Theorems are the most famous examples, but there are plenty of others.

I know that the connections between mathematical logic and **computer science** run very deep, but I have never been able to find a clear answer on what seems like a straightforward and important question: **Can one think of a programming language as a formal system?** Would this work for some languages but not other? In that case, what about the **C programming language**? Might it, perhaps, work only if we considered a **subset** of C or some other language?

If one could think of C or another language as a formal system, would applying well-known theorems about formal systems yield any interesting results?

### Potential Examples of Axioms and Statements in C

C, like almost all programming languages, contains **a form of arithmetic** within itself. It contains the usual axioms that one learns at school with respect to the **addition, subtraction and multiplication of integers**. (Things get a little more interesting when we move to *division* and non-integers; C does not always return the expected result when dividing integers and working with floats.)

The rules of arithmetic provide the **axioms**. As for the **statements**, C includes the `==` operator, which we can use to test whether an asserted arithmetical equality is true, e.g. this minimal C program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    if (2+2 == 4) {
        printf("This is the expected result.\n");
    } else {
        printf("Something's gone badly wrong!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

One could use a C program on the above lines to test whether each of a batch of arithmetical statements was true - or, for that matter, well-formed.

Comment: As far as I know, the C language *is* a formal system (where many constructions are left as Undefined Behavior). Beware that none of the C arithmetic operations fully matches the corresponding mathematical operations, due to finiteness.

Comment: Also note that the arithmetic system is not fully axiomatized, leaving room for peculiarities of the underlying processor. But 2+2 will yield 4 on most machines :-)

Comment: Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was cross-posted.

Comment: I don't understand, why should cross posting be disallowed? It's perfectly allowed in MSE and MO with physics. It allows one to get different prespectives @D.W.

Comment: @Buraian, you can refer to the link I provided to find extensive discussion of that policy issue.